# Манипуляции с символами строки

Tags: php, строки

Необходимо вывести строку содержащую пробелы до заданной позиции, на которой необходимо отобразить её порядковый номер. Например для позиции номер 3 строка должна содержать 2 
пробела и цифру 3. Пишу следующий код:

```
<?
$out = "";
$i = 3;
$out[$i] = $i;
echo "$out";
?>
```

Выводит `Array`. Разве переменную заключённую в двойные кавычки php не расценивает как строку? Как мне добиться результата?

Comment: С переменной все правильно, а вот обращение к определенному символу строки необходимо осуществлять через фигурные скобки $out{$i}. А правильное решение привел в ответе.

Comment: В документации прочитал, что можно как через фигурные, так и через квадратные. В любом случае не помогает. А ваш ответ работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function SpaceNumberWrite($number) {
       $out = '';
       for($i = 1; $i < $number; $i++) {
          $out .= ' ';
       }
       $out .= $number;
    return $out;
    }

echo SpaceNumberWrite(1).'<br />';
echo SpaceNumberWrite(2).'<br />';
echo SpaceNumberWrite(3);

/* Результат
1
 2
  3
*/
```